# How do I interpret this wiring schematic?

Tags: wiring, bathtub, light, fans

I am getting confused by the wiring schematic. For this Broan 696 bathroom vent fan it has 2 outlet plugins(one for fan, one for light) the fan outlet has black and white wires. The light outlet has a black and a blue wire. Then ground.  But in the schematic it has red wire to blue wire. Where does this red wire come from?

[image]

Comment: It is a Broan 696

Comment: The solid box on bottom left looks like a switch box.  should be on the wall.  The red will come from the switches, in a 3 wire(plus ground) cable.  So run your power to the switches, then to the fan/light with the black, red, white and ground.

Comment: You should have a switch box on the wall with two switches and a cable feeding power, and also a /3 cable from there to the fan, IE a cable with black, white, red, and bare copper wires in it (usually those colors but doesn't have to be).  Do you have all that?  Can you add a photo of the switch box clearly showing the cables and wires in it?

Answer (score 1):

The red wire in the schematic is the switched hot from the switch controlling the light. There is no need for it to be red, it is not part of the Fan/Light wiring, it is assumed to be existing in the house wiring. The wiring coming into the Fan/Light needs to have a white neutral wire, 2 switched hot wires, and an equipment ground wire. If it does not, the Fan/Light is not suitable to be installed unless the house wiring is changed appropriately.